# Still Run time error 1004 'Unable to get the VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction class

Tags: excel, vba

I got this error and I tried to fixed with many solution, but I don't know why this error is happening. Could you help me to fix this problem? In this code I have twice used `VLookup` function same source, different only Worksheet name and column. Another one can compile this code and don't have any error.

I'm doing, `VLookup` item on column B of worksheet "ImportData2" match with column A of worksheet "Noallocate" if match show result of `VLookup` at column Q of worksheet "ImportData2"

[image]

[image]

get this error

[image]

Source code:

```
 'Vlook up function no import
    Dim Vrow1 As Long
    Dim myLookupValue1 As String
    Dim myFirstColumn1 As Long
    Dim myLastColumn1 As Long
    Dim myColumnIndex1 As Long
    Dim myFirstRow1 As Long
    Dim myLastRow1 As Long
    Dim myVLookupResult1 As String
    Dim myTableArray1 As Range
    For Vrow1 = 2 To 99999
        myLookupValue1 = Workbooks("ExpenseData.xlsm").Worksheets("ImportData2").Range("B" & Vrow).Value
        myFirstColumn1 = 1
        myLastColumn1 = 2
        myColumnIndex1 = 2
        myFirstRow1 = 2
        myLastRow1 = Workbooks("ExpenseData.xlsm").Worksheets("Noallocate").Range("b1").End(xlDown).Row

        With Workbooks("ExpenseData.xlsm").Worksheets("Noallocate")
            Set myTableArray1 = .Range(.Cells(myFirstRow1, myFirstColumn1), .Cells(myLastRow1, myLastColumn1))
        End With
      myVLookupResult1 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(myLookupValue1, myTableArray1, myColumnIndex1, False)  'xxx
      Workbooks("ExpenseData.xlsm").Worksheets("ImportData").Range("Q" & Vrow).Value = myVLookupResult1 'xxx
   Next 'end function no import
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the next code, please. It would be a good habit to have 'Option Explicit' on top of your module. This will oblige you to declare all variables. It looks, your code iterates using `Vrow1` but inside the loop you used `Vrow`... I discovered it only after trying to make your code a little friendlier. It is not good to use big variables name instead of `1`, `2`. This can only make the code more difficult to be understood by looking at it. As short it would be, as easy to be understood and debugged:

```
Sub testVlookup()
 Dim Wb As Workbook, Vrow1 As Long, lastRDat As Long, wsNoall As Worksheet
 Dim wsImpD2 As Worksheet, myLookupValue1 As String, myLastRow1 As Long
 Dim myVLookupResult1 As String, myTableArray1 As Range

    Set Wb = Workbooks("ExpenseDataMcframe.xlsm")
    Set wsNoall = Wb.Worksheets("Noallocate")
    Set wsImpD2 = Wb.Worksheets("ImportData2")
    myLastRow1 = wsNoall.Range("b" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastRDat = wsImpD2.Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Vrow1 = 2 To lastRDat
        myLookupValue1 = wsImpD2.Range("B" & Vrow1).value

        Set myTableArray1 = wsNoall.Range(wsNoall.Cells(2, 1), wsNoall.Cells(myLastRow1, 2))

        On Error Resume Next 'for the case when lookup_value is not found
        myVLookupResult1 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(myLookupValue1, myTableArray1, 2, False)  'xxx
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
             Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
             Wb.Worksheets("ImportData").Range("Q" & Vrow1).value = "Not a mach"
        Else
            Wb.Worksheets("ImportData").Range("Q" & Vrow1).value = myVLookupResult1 'xxx
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0
   Next
End Sub
```

When the lookup_value is not found, the code will return (on Q:Q column) "Not a match" and you must check the specific code/whatever it is...

Comment: @Mameaw Yaary: Did you test my code? I saw only an attempt to edit my code. This is not an appropriate way... I tested the code using my workbook and I kept yours, but commented. It should be obvious what is it about...

Comment: I try your code still same error until now. I just edit file name only "Becase I don't want to show file name, I forgot rename only that". And your code still can't complie on vba. This is error "Run-time error 1004 Unable to get the VLookup property of the WokrsheetFunction class."

Comment: And I also try to create new workworksheet and seperatate module in vba, can't complie this code also.

Comment: This error type is raised by VBA when the lookup_value is not found. I thought your ranges where from to retrieve the values are checked and have the same format. The above code works very well on my computer. I will adapt the code to retrieve "Not a mach" (in Q:Q column) in such cases, without raising the error. And, if you wonted me to use a dummy workbook name, you should ask for that. I used to use `ThisWorkbook` and your name was gray-out. You did not say anything, even  about the code behavior... This is not in your advantage. I could adapt the code in this way 2 days before.